# Pass context to enum. Is my solution correct?

Tags: android, enums

I want to populate a spinner with enum using string resource (for localization).
Here my testing solution :

MyEnum.java:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FRENCH(R.string.french, new double[] {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, "French"),
    ENGLISH(R.string.english, new double[] {0.2, 0.3, 0.1}, "English"),
    SPANISH(R.string.spanish, new double[] {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, "Spanish"),
    ITALIAN(R.string.italian, new double[] {0.6, 0.6, 0.6}, "Italian");

    private final int mResourceId;
    private final double[] mTruc;
    private final String mDefault;

    private static Context sContext;

    private MyEnum(final int id, final double[] truc, final String def) {
        mResourceId = id;
        mTruc = truc;
        mDefault = def;
    }

    static void setContext(final Context context) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "setContext 0");
        sContext = context;
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "setContext 1");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (sContext != null) {
            return sContext.getString(mResourceId);
        } else {
            return mDefault;
        }
    }

    double[] getTruc() {
        return mTruc;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextView;

    protected static final String TAG = "SPINNER";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyEnum.setContext(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MyEnum>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MyEnum.values()));

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
                MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum) spinner.getSelectedItem();
                String truc = "";
                for (double d : myEnum.getTruc()) {
                    truc += d + " ";
                }
                mTextView.setText(myEnum.toString() + " " + truc);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestSpinner</string>
    <string name="french">French</string>
    <string name="english">English</string>
    <string name="spanish">Spanish</string>
    <string name="italian">Italian</string>
</resources>
```

fr/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestSpinner</string>
    <string name="french">Français</string>
    <string name="english">Anglais</string>
    <string name="spanish">Espagnol</string>
    <string name="italian">Italien</string>
</resources>
```

After several tests, it seems to work as expected.
Is my solution correct and without memory leaks as you can find with other solutions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I used a custom ArrayAdapter and the enum only gives the resource id.

**Edit** : use simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml for dropDownView.

Here MyEnumArrayAdapter.java :

```
class MyEnumArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyEnum> {
    private final MyEnum[] mMyEnum;

    public MyEnumArrayAdapter(final Context context, final MyEnum[] data) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
        mMyEnum = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }

    private View initView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent, final int layout) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final Context context = getContext();

        if (row == null) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            row = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final MyEnum item = mMyEnum[position];
        viewHolder.textView.setText(context.getText(item.getResourceId()));
        return row;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }
}
```

My new MyEnum.java:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FRENCH(R.string.french, new double[] {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}),
    ENGLISH(R.string.english, new double[] {0.2, 0.3, 0.1}),
    SPANISH(R.string.spanish, new double[] {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}),
    ITALIAN(R.string.italian, new double[] {0.6, 0.6, 0.6});

    private final int mResourceId;
    private final double[] mTruc;

    private MyEnum(final int id, final double[] truc) {
        mResourceId = id;
        mTruc = truc;
    }

    int getResourceId() {
        return mResourceId;
    }

    double[] getTruc() {
        return mTruc.clone();
    }
}
```

And a part of MainActivity.java:

```
final MyEnumArrayAdapter adapter = new MyEnumArrayAdapter(this, MyEnum.values());
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Is this solution better ?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it looks very nice. Now add some tests and documentation and it should be beautiful.

Comment: What kinds of tests do you think ? I tested with an emulator with marshmallow and 2 real devices (one with lollipop and the other with kitkat). Worked as expected and no problem detected. Perhaps just use a custom layout for the dropDownView.

Comment: I'm talking about some [unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/index.html). Like "Depending on the language, will all enums return the correct String from the resource id?" or "Will the adapter return the correct views for a given array of enums?".

Comment: OK. Never use unit tests. I'm not a professional and just make some little applications for pleasure. But it's never too late. This is the occasion for me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a potential memory leak.

```
static void setContext(final Context context) {
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "setContext 0");
    sContext = context;
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "setContext 1");
}
```

Storing the context of an Activity is a bad idea. If you really have to then save the application context by simply calling context.getApplicationContext(). But then again, what are you trying to accomplish with  this setup? I mean this enum seems somehow broken. Is mutable and does stuff that I think should be done somewhere else.

Also besides strings there are also [string-arrays](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) which can be uses for the languages. These then can be feed to the adapter.

Comment: If I want to use resource strings (essentially for localization), I must have the context of the application. Is there a simple way to pass the application context to the enum using the toString method ?

Comment: This is just a test. The getTruc method will be changed. In fact, I know I can do it without enum but I just wanted to test this solution.

Comment: Even if its just a test we should strive for a good concept and implementation. Way to often these 'test', 'examples' or 'prove of concepts' are delivered to customers and then hell brakes loose. But back to topic. So the mayor problem is, that you need context in the toString method right? Why not add a another method that expects a context and then returns the translated String? Since you are using the toString to present the value to an user the context is already given.